# Converting Data Types from integer to char*

Tags: arduino

I am working on a school project that includes a list of i2C IDs that match particular sensors that I am using.

```
//DO, pH, Electric Conductivity, temperature
int channel_ids[] = {97, 99, 100, 102};
```

The problem is that I am trying to connect this to a particular API that uses different numbers to represent its channels and is a character pointer.

```
// where 70 is id for temperature for the API that I am trying to connect to.
char *GTAPI_ChannelID="70"
```

I want to create an IF statement that looks something like:

```
if (GTAPI_ChannelID == "70") {
   channel_ids="102";
}
```

but I do not know how to do this when channel_ids is an integer and GTAPI_ChannelID is a character pointer.

Thanks

Comment: The `atoi()` function from `stdlib.h` can cast a char pointer to an int: `if (atoi(GTAPI_ChannelID) == 70){...}`. Next though, what you're doing with `channel_ids` within the `if` isn't doing what you think it will. `channel_ids` is an array, indexed by element number. You go on to try to assign a character string to it.

Comment: Data conversion may loose data and would not be good idea. When the `IDs` and `strings` are `static`, why can't you used `array` where `index` of the array is the `ID` and `content` is the `string`. The confusion i have it you mentioned API, are these APIs or strings? If they are APIs then may be use function pointers

Comment: comparison by == on C char strings is wrong (and dangerous), assignment to

Comment: It's a very big difference between `102` and `"102"`